# Not able to run prisma deploy: Error: Cluster undefined does not exist

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am learning graphql and following this tutorial https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/1-getting-started/

i have installed prisma using `npm install -g prisma` and while running this command `prisma deploy` in server folder iam getting this error:

```
config CWD /Users/aravind/tekie/hackernews-react-apollo/server +0ms
  config HOME /Users/aravind +2ms
  config definitionDir /Users/aravind/tekie/hackernews-react-apollo/server/database +5ms
  config definitionPath /Users/aravind/tekie/hackernews-react-apollo/server/database/prisma.yml +0ms
  cli { isGlobal: true } +0ms
  StatusChecker setting status checker +0ms
  cli command id deploy +7ms
  cli:plugincache Got plugin from cache +0ms
  cli:plugincache /Users/aravind/Library/Caches/prisma/plugins.json +1ms
  cli:plugincache Got plugin from cache +1ms
  cli:plugincache /Users/aravind/Library/Caches/prisma/plugins.json +0ms
  plugins findCommand prisma-cli-core +0ms
  plugin requiring command +0ms
  cli-engine:plugins:manager requiring /usr/local/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/prisma-cli-core +0ms
  portfinder:defaultHosts exports._defaultHosts is: [ '0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1', '::1', 'fe80::1', 'fe80::18fb:a4af:2b44:3fea', '192.168.43.100', '2405:204:6209:18b0:144f:bac3:86ac:3cdf', '2405:204:6209:18b0:fd46:e3b7:952f:d569', 'fe80::1c49:3cff:fe5f:7e16', 'fe80::3e5f:ab5d:16dd:a8bf' ] +0ms
  cli-engine:plugins:manager required +538ms
  plugin required command +540ms
  StatusChecker setting status checker +569ms
Error: Cluster undefined does not exist.
    at Deploy.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/prisma-cli-core/src/commands/deploy/index.ts:175:13)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/prisma-cli-core/dist/commands/deploy/index.js:42:23)
    at Object.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/prisma-cli-core/dist/commands/deploy/index.js:23:53)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/prisma-cli-core/dist/commands/deploy/index.js:14:58)
    at <anonymous>
  util timed out +0ms
Exiting with code: 0
```

up to this all the set-up was correct and I am unable to run this command. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please additionally share your `prisma.yml` file and the `~/.prisma/config.yml` file? **Please remove all sensitive information before sharing it here**. For example, the `config.yml` file contains a `cloudSessionKey` which shouldn't be shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also witnessed the same problem that you identified while trying to deploy the service, following the same tutorial.

I stumbled upon the "solution" from the tutorial writer itself, [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql/issues/650):

> The current version of the tutorial just works with Prisma CLI
>   versions < 1.7, so be sure you have some 1.6.x version installed. You
>   can check your current prisma version with this command:
>
> ```
> prisma version
> ```
>
> Then uninstall and install the correct version like this:
>
> ```
> npm uninstall -g prisma
> ```
>
> `npm install -g prisma@1.6.3`

Answer (score -1):

Can you run with yarn prisma deploy after download yarn not using npm prisma deploy